# JQuery: Assigning value to td span if span is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with functions connected to a database. If the player score exists, the value is assigned to the td span. If there is no player score, no value is assigned to the td span. I'm trying to populate the span with "0" if a score doesn't exist, or if the td span is empty.

```
$("table tbody tr").children('td').find("span.playerScore").each(function () {
    var test = $(this).text();
    if (test === "") {
        $(this).parent("td").children('span').text() = "0";
    }
})
```

This isn't working. I definitely feel it's something obvious and I'm just blind so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `.text()` is a method, you don't assign values to methods, you pass them in parenthesis: `.text("0")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This...

```
$(this).parent("td").children('span').text() = "0";
```

is not how you set the text of an element.

You  need to pass the text as an argument to `text`:

```
$(this).parent("td").children('span').text("0");
```

Comment: Yep. I'm blind. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to use the `:empty` selector. That can save a couple lines of code.

It's important to note that the value of the text has to be enclosed inside parenthesis.

```
$("table tbody tr").children('td').find("span.playerScore").filter(":empty").each(function () {
    $(this).parent("td").children('span').text("0");
})
```